# Cannot Bind dynamically generated input radio on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sass

I am trying to make a dropdown based off of some dynamically generated radio inputs that i cannot control. I have it working in a codepen, but those radio inputs are not being dynamically generated. I feel like I am close, but may be having some syntax issues. Any suggestions?

jQuery:

```
      (function () {
          return $('.cart-dropdown-select').each(function (idx, el) {
            var $select, $trigger, $radio;
            $select = $(el);
            $trigger = $select.find('.trigger');
            $radio = $select.find(".radio");
            $select.removeClass("is-open");
            $select.on("click", function (e) {
              return $select.toggleClass("is-open");
            });
            $select.on("click", "input[name='radio']", function (e) {
              console.log($(this));
              $select.removeClass("no-selection");
              return $select.toggleClass("is-open");
              $(this).parent().addClass("checked");
            });
          });

      }).call(this);
```

SCSS:

```
.cart-dropdown-select {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 24px 6px 6px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
  border-radius: 4px;

  &.no-selection {
    label:first-of-type {
      display: block;
      height: auto;
    }
    .radio:first-of-type {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  .radio, .enabled{
    display: none;
  }

  &.is-open {
    input + label {
      margin-top: 3px;
      &:first-of-type {
        margin-top: 0;
      }
      &::after {
        content: "\A";  // hack to force linebreak
        white-space: pre;
      }
    }
    .radio, .enabled{
      display: block;
    }
  }


  &.is-open input,
  &.is-open input + label,
  input:checked,
  input:checked + label, .checked{
    display: block;
    height: auto;
  }

  input,
  input + label {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  &::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border: 6px solid #fff;
    border-top-color: blue;
    top: 11px;
    right: 6px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 9px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  input[type="radio"] {
    display: none;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    + label {
      position: relative;
      color: blue;
      &:hover {
        color: grey;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    }

    &:disabled {
      + label {
        color: blue;
        padding-left: 0;
        &::before {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    }

    &:checked {
      + label {
        color: grey;
        &::before {
          background: $pop;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

HTML (layout example):

```
<div class='cart-dropdown-select is-open no-selection'>
     <div class="radio">
      <input disabled='disabled' id='disabled' name='radios' type='radio' value='disabled'>
      <label for='disabled'>Select Option</label>
  </div>

      <div class="radio">
        <input id='foo1' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo1'>
        <label for='foo1'>Foo1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio">
        <input id='foo2' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo2'>
        <label for='foo2'>Foo2</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio">
        <input id='foo3' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo3'>
        <label for='foo3'>Foo3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Also a link to the codepen, again this content in the codepen is not being dynamically driven, so it works fine there.
https://codepen.io/ascarb1/pen/LKdKjE

Comment: Are you sure the Radio buttons are painted before this is called?  How are you dynamically building them?  If you throw a break point in the middle of this function and watch this `$select.find(".radio");` what do you see?

Comment: So this jQuery is being loaded along with the dynamic content JS, the think I am frustrated with the most is that when I console.log($(this)) and change the "input" to a div class, it finds the div class without an issue and the rest of the code works fine, but I need it to find these inputs. The div class is also dynamically generated.

Comment: also, after adding that .find() it sees the div class .radio. The input's do not have a class.

Comment: `"input[name='radio']"` should be `"input[name='radios']"` Notice the s

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, the HTML above are examples, the name of the dynamic radio inputs is "radio"

Comment: Drop a break point after `$radio = $select.find(".radio");`.  What do you see if you watch this statement `$radio.find("input")`.

Comment: Yea, for some reason when binding it, the jquery could not find the inputs that way. I think you were right on the first one, this is somehow getting loaded before the radio inputs were. But its all good, I ended up just reworking the HTML surrounding the dynamic content a bit  and made a couple small changes to the jQuery. Seems to work now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing a bit of the HTML around so the bind can happen within a class that is not being dynamically loaded. This seems to have worked. Feel free to leave feedback if there is still a better solution:

jQuery:

```
      (function () {
          return $('.cart-dropdown-select').each(function (idx, el) {
            var $select, $trigger, $radio;
            $select = $(el);
            $trigger = $select.find('.trigger');
            $radio = $(".radio");
            $select.removeClass("is-open");
            $select.on("click", function (e) {
              return $select.toggleClass("is-open");
            });
            $select.on("click", ".enabled input", function() {
              $select.toggleClass("no-selection");
              $(this).parentsUntil($radio).toggleClass("checked");
              return $select.toggleClass("is-open");
            });
          });

      }).call(this);
```

HTML (Example):

```
<div class='cart-dropdown-select is-open no-selection'>
      <input disabled='disabled' id='disabled' name='radios' type='radio' value='disabled'>
      <label for='disabled'>Select Option</label>

      <div class="radio">
        <label class="enabled" for='foo1'>
          <input id='foo1' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo1'>
        Foo1</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio">
        <label class="enabled" for='foo2'>
          <input id='foo2' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo2'>
        Foo2</label>
      </div>

      <div class="radio">
        <label class="enabled" for='foo3'>
          <input id='foo3' name='radios' type='radio' value='foo3'>
        Foo3</label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The SCSS did not change.

Comment: Glad ya got it working.  If it's possible I'd suggest waiting till everything is painted then start binding up events.